# "climb down from a tree" or "come down from a tree"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What's the expression when someone has taken an extreme position and for reasons of ego finds it difficult to soften his position? Something along the lines of "coming down from the tree," maybe? 
As in: I initially accepted a full settlement freeze, but eventually changed my mind. However, for diplomatic reasons, I found it difficult to...(come down from the tree?)"

Comment: We're going to need to know how you want to use your expression. Please see the checklists on the [*-request] tags for hints on formulating this type of question: help the community to help you. [Words](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) | [Phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info)

Comment: I'm afraid the community is getting stricter on this type of question. Please see the checklists.

Comment: you must change the title of this question, Tamar

Answer (score 2):

*Climb down* is a phrase used where you have suggested "come down from the tree".

> *British*
>   Withdraw from a position taken up in argument or negotiation:
>   *‘he was forced to climb down over the central package in the bill’*
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/climb_down)]

Comment: I was going to edit the question title to clarify what expression was being sought, but this phrase is actually an answer.

Comment: @Robbie Did you check the link to Oxford? It **is** the main definition.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, Andrew. I looked only at the question, not the expansion. Duh!